# sql query to replace

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a string in my description field in MySQL like this :

> "text text text pass:123456789 text text text"

I want to replace 4 characters after "pass:" to star.
result:

> "text text text pass:****56789 text text text"

I use this

```
UPDATE table_name SET field = REPLACE(description , '123456789', '****56789') WHERE field LIKE '%123456789%';
```

if password change my query dont work.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: mariaDB @Strawberry

Comment: what do you mean with  "if password change my query dont work."  .?? . try explain better  .. add a  proper data sample

Comment: Ok; which version of MariaDB

Comment: for example: "text text text pass:987654321 text text text" cant find 987654321 and replace with ****54321

Comment: @scaisedge they mean if the password no longer fits the pattern

Comment: MariaDB 10.4.10 @Strawberry

Comment: then update your question and also show the query /code  you use for select or match the password ..

Comment: Never used MariaDB before but I think what you're looking for is REGEXP_REPLACE which lets you build a regular expression to identify your "pass:" pattern and replace the first four characters with asterisks which follow your pattern

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in my comment you could do this with REGEXP_REPLACE, assuming your comment that this post is regarding MariaDB instead of mysql is more correct.

So given your example I'd write the following statement:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field = REGEXP_REPLACE(description , '\bpass:\w{4}', 'pass:****') WHERE field LIKE '%123456789%';
```

If you're not familiar with regular expression what this does is basically:

- search a word that begins with "pass:" and then has four additional characters after it in the boundary of a word.
- replace the found strings with "pass:****"

A word in regular expressions is btw. something that contains alphanumeric and underscore characters. 
Valid would be for example "This_is_1_word", "Word", "123153".

So my example will only work with passwords that only contain the mentioned alphanumeric and underscore characters.

To fit every need you'd need to specify which characters are allowed for the password. I could adapt the given regular expression based on your specs